# Sharing Visual Studio code snippets amongst a team of developers

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

Has anyone come up with a good way to share a set of Visual Studio Code Snippets (actual .snippet files that Visual studio uses) amongst a team of developers automatically?  It would be great for other developers on my team to benefit from shortcuts I've created for myself, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is very old, but I found another good way (IMO) for sharing snippets, maybe in addition to the solution @Kevin Dente provided: **using git**!!

I shared successfully snippets and project templates creating an ad hoc git repository named **snippets.git**, I cloned it into the *MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2015\Code Snippets* folder and now I can add, edit or delete snippets from *MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2015\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets* (or *Visual Basic* folder), then commit and push to make them available to all other team members with the same configuration.

The principle is applicable also to the project templates, you can create a **templates.git** repository and clone it to the *MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2015\Templates* folder, then create the templates under the *MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#* folder (or *Visual Basic* folder).

This way the developers can periodically pull the two repositories and have up to date snippets and templates, available almost everywhere the git server is reachable (anyone said github? or bitbucket?).

Of course I am using Visual Studio 2015, but the method can be used with previous and, I think, future versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2018 now and the VS Code team has added this feature (currently in preview)

See [this ticket for more info](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8102)

Comment: The feature in question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.